# Quartz removes a job if it queues itself while running

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I have the following problem with Quartz:

A job is scheduled to run every 10 minutes. Sometimes (rarely) the job might take longer than 10 minutes. In such cases, Quartz will put the same job on the queue to run after the current one (same job) is executing. Normally that is no problem; the job will run two times in a row and all is well and functioning. However, in some cases, the second time the job will also take more than 10 minutes. I would expect that Quartz will just put it in the queue one more time. Instead this job never gets queued and is not run again. Everything else is normal besides this job, which never runs again until the system is restarted.

Is this the expected behavior? Is there any way that I can modify it to better suit my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with more jobs running and the QUARTZ thread pool being maxed out.